# Navigation Controller back button image manipulation

Tags: xcode, swift, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I am, no matter what I try, unable to change the back button colour and default image.

Here is what it looks like rite now:

[image]

The leftmost arrow is the default and the right most is my custom arrow.

This is how I set it up in storyboard:

[image]

[image]

How do I remove that pesky default image and replace it with my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button you are adding is overriten by the default back button provided by the navBar. The only way you could do that is by adding it from within the code and by creating an UIButton inside the UIBarButton with an image and/or text, you should set its action a popViewController.